# What are the units of enzyme activity?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

I was looking at [this](http://www.uic.edu/classes/bios/bios100/labs/graph05.jpg) graph of turnip [peroxidase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxidase) activity and I saw that they use units of 1/sec for enzyme activity. What does this unit intuitively represent and how is it calculated?

Comment: The Wikipedia "Enzyme Assay" page looks pretty good.

Answer (score 7):

This refers to the [turnover number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnover_number) (a.k.a k<sub>cat</sub> or k<sub>2</sub>) of an enzyme and is usually calculated using [Michaelis-Menten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis-Menten_kinetics) kinetics. Jump to the summary at the end if you want a simple answer. If you want a more thorough answer, consider the following chemical equation:

> [E] + [S] ⇌ [ES] → [E] + [P]

This says that a certain concentration of enzyme mixed with a certain concentration of substrate will first combine and form a complex depending on the enzyme's [affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity) for the substrate. Then the enzyme complex will generate a product depending on the enzyme's ability to convert the transition state into product. The k<sub>1</sub> constant is the arrow moving from [E] + [S] → [ES] and the k<sub>-1</sub> is the arrow moving from [ES] → [E] + [S] (they oppose each other). The k<sub>2</sub> constant is the arrow moving from [ES] → [E] + [P].

> V<sub>o</sub> = [ES]k<sub>2</sub>

- V<sub>o</sub> - this is the rate that product is being formed, which can be measured.
- [ES] - this is the concentration of enzyme-substrate complexes.
- k<sub>2</sub> - this is a constant value comparing the two.

This can also be expressed in terms of maximum rate:

> V<sub>max</sub> = [E]<sub>T</sub>k<sub>2</sub>

- V<sub>max</sub> - V<sub>max</sub> is catalytic rate when [E]<sub>T</sub> = [ES] (when all of the enzyme present is bound to substrate/saturated).
- [E]<sub>T</sub> - [E]<sub>T</sub> is the total enzyme concentration. [E]<sub>T</sub> = [E] + [ES].
- k<sub>2</sub> - the k<sub>cat</sub> is the catalytic constant. It is a constant indicating how quickly an enzyme can convert substrates into products. It is easily observed by this equation.

#### Summary

So k<sub>2</sub> is basically an indicator of how efficiently or quickly an enzyme operates. Not all enzymes follow standard [Michaelis-Menten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis-Menten_kinetics) kinetics. For example, the [allosteric properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allosteric_regulation) of some enzymes cause a non-linear saturation curve. Because of this, the turnover number is commonly referred to. The turnover number's units of s<sup>-1</sup> indicate one product molecule per second, so a turnover rate of 3000 means you can create 3000 products in 1 second at V<sub>max</sub>.